# Google Analytics and Widgets

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, widget

What is the best way to track widget installs and clicks on multiple sites using google Analytics?

For eg:
I am building a javascript widget (say domain www.widgetSource.com). This widget is installed on www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com. I have the widget setup to track clicks using GA. But currently it all shows up under 1 big bucket, say widgetInteractions.

What I would like to do is

1. Overall widgetInteractions (i am able to see this now)
2. Track widgetInteractions individually for www.domain1.com and
   www.domain2.com

Theoretically, I see myself passing some sort of unique identifier to GA to track domain1 vs domain2. but not entirely sure how to do it.. 
Is this possible using GA?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!